# How to subclass Bundle with custom initiliser

Tags: swift, bundle

I want to do the following, but swift compiler does not allow it. Is there a workaround to achieve the same?

```
class MyBundle:Bundle
{
    public var key : String
    public var cert : String

    convenience init?(key:String, cert:String) {    
        self.key = key
        self.cert = cert
        super.init()
    }
```

Looks silly, but I am really stuck on this :)

Comment: You must call  a designated initializer of the superclass 'Bundle'

Answer (score -1):

You have to call the designated initializer of `Bundle`.

```
class MyBundle: Bundle {

    public var key : String
    public var cert : String

    init?(key: String, cert: String, path: String) {
        self.key = key
        self.cert = cert
        super.init(path: path)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I tried also - but I don't known what to provide in "path", also I want a non failing constructor